is there any built-in clipboard for ubuntu 22.04 in 2024?
I've been using CopyQ for a while, but it doesn't work as smoothly as before. I faced several issues while copying and pasting. Is there any built-in clipboard or other clipboard you guys use that is better than CopyQ?

https://askubuntu.com/a/1528803/289138 ?

This question is similar to: Clipboard Manager for Ubuntu 16.04, 18.04. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
